# How I can log queries for every (or specific) user in a separate file in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Database and I want to open access to it for several users that should be able to execute some queries but I need to monitor them. I know I can enable all logs but in this case I will log application user logs also, which will contains a millions of them.

Comment: database:PostgreSQL 9.3; development environment:Linux  (Ubuntu Server/CentOs)

Comment: database:PostgreSQL 9.3; development environment:Linux  (Ubuntu Server/CentOs); database framework:JPA/Hibernate. Please notice that users will connect directly to DB (no application interfaces are designed for them). They should be able to delete/insert/select some data in case of any issues, and we need to log this just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend entirely on the platform being used. You need the type of environment where each query is executed and/or reported alongside the connection context.

For example, in NodeJS, if you use [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), you have access to the `client` object along with each query executed, and that object has all the connection details, including the user name.

You would need to address this issue for a specific database + development environment + database framework. Without these 3 variables known there can be no answer.

The only alternative is when a database accessed completely through functions that add the functionality of logging each request details against the current user name. But this isn't a very good architecture to begin with.